# Excluding binary files from git diff --no-index

Tags: git, diff

I'm calling Git on a Windows machine to perform a diff between two folders unrelated to a Git repository. These folders contain sizable binary files, and as thus calling `git diff` directly on the folders is unacceptably slow.

I would like to be able to be able to tell Git not to process the binary files to improve the performance. This would be best achieved using `exclude` options (i.e `'!:<file>'`) for which there's numerous examples out there - if I wasn't using `--no-index` to specify the 2 paths I want to compare.

So I have two questions:

- Does the file exclusion system afforded by `git diff` apply to the files within folders in the event of comparing a folder with another using `git diff --no-index <path> <path>` ?
- If so, how to express it ? `git diff --no-index <path> <path> "!:<file>"` only ever triggers the usage output, whether I add the optional `--` or not.

My alternative would be seeking the files inside the folders myself, but I would be losing `git diff`'s built-in analysis of creation/deletion/renaming of files.